# how to fill matrix using range without numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a matrix of zeros using lists, and I want to fill it based on matrix size, but I want the numbers to come sequentially.

I tried the following

```
matrix = []
for i in range(3):
    a =[]
    for j in range(3):
        a.append(i+j)
    matrix.append(a)
```

I get this:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

but the expected is:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

thanks

Comment: For the 2nd row, `i==1` and `j==0`, what else can `i+j` be?  Sometimes we need to test several iterations to make sure the code is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your outer `range` loop with a step to provide the base value for each level. In this case, just change:

```
for i in range(3):
```

to:

```
for i in range(0, 9, 3):
```

It might be slightly more readable to phrase it in terms of a named variable like `dim` (for "dimension"):

```
dim = 3
for i in range(0, dim ** 2, dim):
    a = []
    for j in range(dim):
        a.append(i+j)
    matrix.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on to @ShadowRanger's answer, rather than appending you can use a list comprehension if you would like.

```
dim = 3
matrix = [list(range(i, i+dim)) for i in range(0, dim**2, dim)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply i by 3 like so:

```py
matrix = []
for i in range(3):
    a =[]
    for j in range(3):
        a.append(3*i + j)     <-----
    matrix.append(a)
```